# How to run recursion in class python

Tags: python, class, recursion

I am trying to create a class Matrix which has a method called row_echelon, and I am trying to use recursion, but it's not working.

```
class Matrix:
    def __init__(self,matrix):
        self.matrix = matrix

    def row_echelon(self):
        r, c = self.matrix.shape
        if r == 0 or c == 0:
            return self.matrix

        for i in range(len(self.matrix)):
            if self.matrix[i,0] != 0:
                break
        else:
            new_matrix = self.row_echelon(self.matrix[:,1:])
        
            return np.hstack([self.matrix[:,:1], new_matrix])

        if i > 0:
            ith_row = self.matrix[i].copy()
            self.matrix[i] = self.matrix[0]
            self.matrix[0] = ith_row

        self.matrix[0] = self.matrix[0] / self.matrix[0,0]

        self.matrix[1:] -= self.matrix[0] * self.matrix[1:,0:1]


        new_matrix = self.row_echelon(self.matrix[1:,1:])

        return np.vstack([self.matrix[:1], np.hstack([self.matrix[1:,:1], new_matrix]) ])
```

Here are my input and output:

Input:

```
A = np.array([[4, 7, 3, 8],
              [8, 3, 8, 7],
              [2, 9, 5, 3]], dtype='float')
my_matrix = Matrix(A)
print(my_matrix.row_echelon())
```

Output:

> TypeError
> Traceback (most recent call last)
> Cell In [43], line 5
> 1 A = np.array([[4, 7, 3, 8],
> 2               [8, 3, 8, 7],
> 3               [2, 9, 5, 3]], dtype='float')
> 4 my_matrix = Matrix(A)
> ----> 5 print(my_matrix.row_echelon())
>
> Cell In [42], line 46, in Matrix.row_echelon(self)
> 41 self.matrix[0] = self.matrix[0] / self.matrix[0,0]
> 43 self.matrix[1:] -= self.matrix[0] * self.matrix[1:,0:1]
> ---> 46 new_matrix = self.row_echelon(self.matrix[1:,1:])
> 48 return np.vstack([self.matrix[:1], np.hstack([self.matrix[1:,:1], new_matrix]) ])
>
> TypeError: Matrix.row_echelon() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

I don't understand which 2 arguments are given?

Comment: You're calling `new_matrix = self.row_echelon(self.matrix[1:,1:])` However your `row_echelon` method does not accept any arguments. That's why you're getting an error.

Comment: The error shows that you are trying to pass the new matrix to `row_echelon` method from the previous one, instead of creating a new `Matrix` instance and then call `new_matrix.row_echelon()` on it instead.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>In `def row_echelon(self):` you define the function to be called with object reference but</strike> in `new_matrix = self.row_echelon(self.matrix[:,1:])` you pass a matrix to the function <strike>as well</strike>. When you call <strike>the</strike>  a class function, it will automatically get an argument of self the object reference <strike>due to the definition</strike> whether you want it or not. And then the `self.matrix[:,1:]` you pass with the function becomes the second argument. The solution is to define your function with another argument <strike>instead of</strike> in addition to `self` and operate on a copy of the matrix instead of the class member `matrix`.

Answer (score 0):

!Update
It finally works. Thank you all so much!! Here is my code:

```
    def row_echelon(self):
    r, c = self.matrix.shape
    if r == 0 or c == 0:
        return self.matrix

    for i in range(len(self.matrix)):
        if self.matrix[i,0] != 0:
            break
    else:
        matrix_2 = self.matrix[:,1:]
        new_matrix = Matrix(matrix_2).row_echelon()
    
        return np.hstack([self.matrix[:,:1], new_matrix])


    if i > 0:
        ith_row = self.matrix[i].copy()
        self.matrix[i] = self.matrix[0]
        self.matrix[0] = ith_row


    self.matrix[0] = self.matrix[0] / self.matrix[0,0]

    self.matrix[1:] -= self.matrix[0] * self.matrix[1:,0:1]

    matrix_2 = self.matrix[1:,1:]
    new_matrix = Matrix(matrix_2).row_echelon()

    return np.vstack([self.matrix[:1], np.hstack([self.matrix[1:,:1], new_matrix]) ])
```